Matlab SNR Function
While examining the snr function in Matlab, I noticed something like this.
When I examined the code and output given in their examples, I noticed that the ratio between average noise power and average signal power the graph. Here is the example:
Fi = 2500;
Fs = 48e3;
N = 1024;
x = sin(2*pi*Fi/Fs*(1:N)) + 0.00001*randn(1,N);

SNR = snr(x,Fs)

Output graph :

When I look at the graph the average power : -85 dB around
When I look at the graph the average power : -3.497 dB
SNR is 81 dB around. (When the graph is examined visually)
I checked the noise power with the command below, wondering if there might be a different ratio between them.
[r noisepow] = snr(x)

Return value in matlab : -59.9333 dB
According to the returned value, the value written on the table is correct, but when I examine the graph, it turns out to be wrong.The values ​​written here and my graphical interpretation do not match for the reasons I have stated. Is there an error or confusion in my comment?
EDIT 1: You may think that it is due to the DC component, but even if that component is not present, the situation I mentioned is the same.
EDIT 2 : Very interesting. When I try it in MATLAB 2023a, I get different results. I tried it in 2019a. But still, when I plot the graph, the average noise is still not like the graph.

When the graph is interpreted, the SNR value still written is not correct. I observe the noise average here at -120 dB levels.

I cannot reproduce your results. When I cut and paste your code into Matlab R2023b, it reports that the signal-to-noise ratio is approximately 96.5 dB, which is almost identical to the 97 dB I get when I compute 20*log10(1/sqrt(2)/0.00001) (the standard deviation of your sinusoid is 1/sqrt(2), and the standard deviation of your noise is 0.00001), and the noise power it returns is -99.5 dB, which is almost identical to the -100 dB I get when I compute 20*log10(0.00001)

@Stephen According to the calculations it is correct, but when I look at the graph it looks different. Can you check out Edit 2? It is also interesting that there are different results between Matlab versions.

Your edit 2 graph looks essentially identical to what Matlab R2023b is producing for me. Maybe there was a bug in the function in Matlab R2019a. Be aware that the power level you see in the graph is not the total power, but rather the power of each frequency component. You need to sum all the magnitudes of the power of each component greater than 0 hz to get the total power and take the square root (don't do this in dB).

@Stephen Is the total power graph different from these graphs? Frankly, I know that there is noise power for each frequency. But I couldn't fully clarify the difference between these two terms. I will search. Is there a resource you recommend?

There may be a bug in your version of Matlab. When I do it in Matlab R2023b, I get the expected results considering the standard deviation of your sinusoid is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and the noise is 0.00001 (see graph below). It reports the signal-to-noise ratio as 96.5 dB, which is almost identical to the 97 dB computed from 20*log10(1/sqrt(2)/0.00001), and it reports the noise power as -99.5 dB, which is almost identical to the -100 dB computed from 20*log10(0.00001).
Be aware that the total noise power is the square root of the sum of the noise power of each frequency component greater than 0 hz, therefore it is not equal to the average power of the noise at each frequency. The graph is showing the components to the Nyquist frequency, so there are N/2 points in the graph above 0 hz. The average noise power is roughly -125 dB at each frequency, so summing all the noise power from each frequency component greater than 0 hz is roughly 20*log10(sqrt(N/2*10^(-125/10))), which is equal to -98 dB and not bad considering the true value is -100 dB. To learn more about this relationship, look up Parseval's theorem.


I understood their relationship :) Really thank you for this explanatory answer.

No worries, and take a look at Parseval's theorem, which I linked the Wikipedia page to, and when you look at that, think about what that means for the variance.

Is it normal for the DC component to be this high?

The DC component is just the signal's average value, so there isn't a "normal" value. The average of randn will be close to zero, but not the sinusoid as there are 53 and 1/3 periods in your window, and that last 1/3 won't average to zero. Also, snr multiplies your signal by a Kaiser window, which doesn't affect all samples uniformly, so can result in a non-zero average value even if your signal's average value was zero.
